# Ошибка установки виджета Select2 через Composer -как исправить?

Tags: yii2, composer, select2

Пробую установить Select2 сначала через консоль Open Server - вообще не устанавливает: 
user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 D:\sites\site\yii2
$ composer require kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 "@dev"

user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 D:\sites\site\yii2
$

а через Gitbush выдает ошибку:[image: scrin]

Composer.json ( D:sites\site\yii2)

```html
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "*",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset":{
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

может быть, дело в 22 строке "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*"  - здесь не хватает чего то?

Comment: composer require "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2"

Comment: //лучше без указания @dev и тогда всё успешно ставится   - Installing kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 (v2.0.9): Downloading (100%). DEV - это версия только разработчикам, для продакшн лучше качать стабильную. Если именно дев надо, тогда composer require "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2":"@dev"

Comment: мне и нужно dev пробую "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2":"@dev"  выдаёт ошибку:
  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 22:
  ...set": "2.*"        /*"kartik-v/yii2-wid
  ---------------------^
  Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'

Comment: Скопировал ваш весь json файл, сделал composer require "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2":"@dev" и успешно установилось: Package operations: 66 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals. Возможно у вас что-то с компосером, может глобально настройки сбиты. Пробуйте сделать composer self-update. Возможно когда добавляли вручную забыли запятую или ещё какой символ.

Comment: проблема решилась просто: вместо "katrik" нужно писать "kartik"

Answer (score 0):

В секцию `require` своего `composer.json` добавьте:

```
"require": {
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev"
}
```

И запустите `composer install` в проекте.